# Creating an int and a switch for my quiz app for the iphone

Tags: objective-c

Right now I have am creating my first quiz app and have been trying to get into objective c. Right now I have my interface set up minus one thing. There are five different categories of questions in my app.The way I have my interface set up I have my buttons set to be hidden or not hidden depending on the int.

For instance I have one category:

```
- (IBAction)Category1:(id)sender{

    Category1.hidden = YES;
    Category2.hidden = YES;
    Category3.hidden = YES;
    Category4.hidden = YES;
    Category5.hidden = YES;

    Answer1.hidden = NO;
    Answer2.hidden = NO;
    Answer3.hidden = NO;
    Answer4.hidden = NO;

    Wrong1.hidden = YES;
    Wrong2.hidden = YES;
    Wrong3.hidden = YES;
    Wrong4.hidden = YES;

    SelectCategory.hidden = YES

    int Category1Question = rand() % 100;
    switch (Category1Question) {
        case 0:
            Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Actual question in the quiz"]
            Right1.hidden = NO;
            Wrong2.hidden = NO;
            Wrong3.hidden = NO;
            Wrong4.hidden = NO;
            Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct answer here"];
            Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer"];
            Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer"];
            Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer"];
            break;
        case 1:
       //(etc. etc.)

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Right now I think I can figure out how to send back to the category selection page, but I would like to send straight to the next random question within the category and maybe even if they answer incorrectly show a label with the right answer. I think I know how to do the incorrect answer part, but having a switch to bring up the next question within the same category. I think that if I created a new int with it set to 0 and everytime they answer a questions it adds 1 to the int and then an if statement saying if the int = the number of questions then return to the category selection page. The problem is I am not sure exactly where I would do this. This app is strictly for my understanding of how coding works, and what I have for the quiz so far has taught me a lot, but I am lost at where to begin.

Any help is appreciated and if I didn't give the appropriate info to help me please let me know.

Comment: Could you narrow this down to an exact question please? I would love to help if it was more specific.

Comment: Sorry I want to know how to go straight to the next question in the same category and stay in the same category until it is done. I don't know the best route or where to even start. Because I only know how to send it back to the category selection menu with the 5 categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    [questionArray addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i]];    
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

int randomIndex = arc4random() % [questionArray count];
int Category1Question = [[questionArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex] intValue]; //cast to int from NSNumber
[questionArray removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    switch (Category1Question) {
        case 0:
            Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Actual question in the quiz"]
            Right1.hidden = NO;
            Wrong2.hidden = NO;
            Wrong3.hidden = NO;
            Wrong4.hidden = NO;
            Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct answer here"];
            Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer"];
            Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer"];
            Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer"];
            break;
        case 1:
       //(etc. etc.)
} //end for
```

A little bit of explanation...
The first part creates an NSMutableArray that stores the numbers 1 - 4. I am assuming that you only have four questions in each category, so I went with the numbers 1 - 4. The second for loop iterates four times, or the number of questions you have in each category. Once inside the loop, a random number (1 - 4) is chosen from the array and it is then removed. This random number is then switched and this leads to the specific question being asked. In this case the number is called `Category1Question`. Note that the for loop cycles four times. This means that every time a question is asked, the switch breaks, then the iteration starts at the top again. A new number is chosen from the array, it is removed, then switched. This time a new question is asked. This process will repeat for as many questions there are. This ensures that all questions are asked and you still stay in the same category.
- Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want to double check if I am doing it properly. So does the NSMutableArray replace the previous int or would it go afterwards? In my instance I have 200 questions in each category So I changed the "For (int i = 0, i < 200; i++) {

eitherway I keep getting this error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression.

Plus do I have to define questionArray in my .h? I tried that as well. Thank you so much helping. I am still incredibly new to this

Comment: No problem. The NSMutableArray can be initialized whenever you need it. You don't have to put it in your .h file. Secondly, I just checked the documentation for NSNumber, and I am positive that `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(int)]` is a legal thing to do. You might try the factory method of the NSNumber class `[NSNumber numberWithInt]`.

Comment: As for replacing the numbers in the NSMutableArray, I only did that so they did not get randomly selected twice. This ensures that only questions number 1 - 200 are used exactly once. **I just figured this out** the reason you are getting that exception is that you are casting an NSNumber to an int when you create the `int Category1Question`. The way to fix this is to write
`int Category1Question = [[questionArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex] intValue];` This should cast the NSNumber to an int and the rest is easy! Hope this helps.

Comment: You can keep asking if you still don't understand and I would be glad to help you. Sorry I had to split that into 3 comments.

Comment: Okay so I've added that to the coding. As far as an interface goes. How would I have an interface that would declare initwithInt? This is literally the last step for my app before it's done and its been frustrating. I really appreciate the help. I kind of understand but at the same time I am still a little lost.

Comment: The error I am getting No visible @interface for 'NSNumber' declares the selector 'initwithInt' I feel like the answer is so easy, but I am just overlooking it.

Comment: NSNumber is a foundation class so you shouldn't be making your own interface for it. In addition, I double checked all of the NSNumber documentation and initWithInt checks outs. You should check out the apple developer page for more info.

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to 

[questionArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

and it successfully builds, but it doesn't proceed to the next question. I run the app, I select a category and the quiz starts. When I answer a question it doesn't successfully go on to the next question within the category. It just goes blank.

Comment: You may be stuck in some sort of infinite loop. If Xcode says the app is still running it may mean that you have some unitialized variable of you are in an infinite loop.

Comment: The app is still running. This thing is driving me crazy. I spent hours typing the questions up before finishing the whole app and now I can't figure this last part. It works the same as the original code I put in.